# Asynchronous form submission to Node server results in 500 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, server

I have a nodejs server that accepts a form and inserts it into a database after an API used to detect nudity says that the image in the request is good to go. It works if I just use the form to submit to the endpoint but now that I have a function that prevents default to send it asynchronously it doesn't work. I used formData to send the entire form data including an image file to be inserted in to the database and captcha but I get a `500 server error` with the response being `Unexpected field` but mutler is expecting the same file name that is being sent over as other posts suggest may have been the problem and  `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` which refers to this line `.then((res) => res.json())`

Code to post to the endoint

```
function submitForm(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var severity = document.getElementById('severity').value;
    var address = document.getElementById('address-input').value;
    var parish = document.getElementById('parish').value;
    var lat = document.getElementById('lat').value;
    var lon = document.getElementById('lon').value;
    // var picture = document.getElementById('pic').value;
    var captcha = document.querySelector('#g-recaptcha-response').value;

    var input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]');

    var data = new FormData(document.getElementById('ticketForm'))
    data.append('pothole', input.files[0])

    fetch("/ticket/add", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",

            },
            body: data
        }).then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)

            //swal(data.msg);

            if (data.msg === "failedCaptcha") {
                swal("Failed captcha")
            }


            if (data.msg === 'success') {
                swal({
                    title: 'Please remember the following code to delete ticket in the future ',
                    text: data.id,
                    type: 'warning',
                    //showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
                }).then(function(result) {
                    // window.location.href = "/index.html";
                })
            }

            if (data.msg === 'nude') {

                swal({
                    title: 'It seems as if our system detected something inappropriate',
                    text: 'Email us with the information provided and we will analyze the image and upload on your behalf',
                    type: 'warning',
                    //showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
                }).then(function(result) {
                    window.location.href = "/index.html";
                })
            }
        })
}
```

Server endpoint code

```
    app.post('/ticket/add', upload, function(req, res) {
    //console.log(req.body)
    // console.log(req.body['g-recaptcha-response'] + " this is captcha result");
    if (!req.body.captcha) {

        return res.json({ "success": false, "msg": "failedCaptcha" });
    }

    var secretKey = process.env.KEY;
    var date = Date.now();
    var id = uniqid();
    var address = req.body.address;

    address = address.split(',');
    address = address[0];

    var ticket = {
        address: address,
        comment: req.body.comment,
        parish: req.body.parish,
        type: req.body.type,
        lat: req.body.lat,
        long: req.body.lon,
        severity: req.body.severity,
        date: moment(date).format("MMM D,YYYY"),
        time: moment(date).format('hh:mm A'),
        picture: req.file,
        deletionid: id,
        ip: req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || req.connection.remoteAddress

    }

    var verifyURL = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secretKey}
                    &response=${req.body.captcha }&remoteip=${req.connection.remoteAddress}`;

    request(verifyURL, (err, response, body) => {
        body = JSON.parse(body);

        //If captcha is not successful 

        if (body.success !== undefined && !body.success) {
            return res.json({ "success": false, "msg": "failedCaptcha" });
        }
        // If captcha is  successful 



        sightengine.check(['nudity', 'wad']).set_file(path.join(req.file.path)).then(function(result) {

            if (result.nudity.safe >= result.nudity.partial && result.nudity.safe >= result.nudity.raw) {

                upload(req, res, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log('Error Occured');
                        return;
                    }

                    db.collection('tickets').save(ticket)
                    return res.json({ "msg": "success", "id": id })
                    console.log("saved to db" + ticket);

                });

            } else {

                return res.json({ "success": false, "msg": "nude" });
                console.log('fail')
            }
        }).catch(function(err) {
            // Error
        });
    })
});
```

UPDATE

Multer Config

```
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'pothole/uploads/')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('pothole');
```

Server output

```
Error: Unexpected field
at makeError (/Users/islander/App/node_modules/multer/lib/make-error.js:12:13)
at wrappedFileFilter (/Users/islander/App/node_modules/multer/index.js:40:19)
at Busboy.<anonymous> (/Users/islander/App/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:114:7)
at emitMany (events.js:127:13)
at Busboy.emit (events.js:201:7)
at Busboy.emit (/Users/islander/App/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:38:33)
at PartStream.<anonymous> (Users/islander/App/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:213:13)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at PartStream.emit (events.js:188:7)
at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (/Users/islander/App/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:51:16)
```

Comment: Can you show the server logs or server output. Also show me your multer `upload` configuration

Comment: @GauravSharma Post updated with requested information

Comment: Set a breakpoint  in the debugger to see what the response text is. That parse error almost always means you endpoint is returning html.

Comment: @JaredSmith It doesn't even hit the breakpoints in the endpoints so I can't see whats going on

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the *client* to see what the response is. Or use `.text()` in place of `.json()`.

Comment: @JaredSmith did just that and console logged the results and it's saying the same unexpected field error. Not sure what else to do, for some reason multer is acting up and I'm not giving it any new fields so I'm not sure why it's saying that